# Run-time error '1004': Sorting in sheetchange

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, columnsorting

I have simple problem using a sort macro. When I import data from my other Workbook, the workbook run the macro below in SheetChange and receive the run-time error.
**HOWEVER, it is working completely fine if I just run the macro when the Workbook is open.**

I don´t know if I have to replace Range with ActiveWorkbook or something, but I think I have tried a lot of different stuff, still without luck :(

I want it to sort from column B, starting in row 13 and until the last row/column. It is dynamic, so it will change every time I import stuff.

```
Sub TESTSORT()
Dim startCol, myCol As String
Dim startRow, lastRow, lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng, cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
startCol = "A"
startRow = 13
lastRow = ws.Range(startCol & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'lastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)

Set Rng = ws.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)

' I GET THE ERROR HERE
Range(.Cells(13, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Sort key1:=Range("B13:B" & lastRow),
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Missing a `.`? `.Range(.Cells(13, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Sort key1:=.Range("B13:B" & lastRow),
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo` - Not sure if you can set Key1 as a big range. Your `Set Rng` looks weird to me. Where is `13A` to result of concatenating 2 numbers?

Comment: Hi PatricK, I think you are right, just like nwhaught. I will try to add the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got some issues inside your With statement... using `Range` instead of `.Range` in several places. I've tried to clean it up a bit below...

```
Sub TESTSORT()
Dim startCol, myCol As String
Dim startRow, lastRow, lastCol As Long
Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng, cell As Range

Set ws2 = ActiveSheet 'Preserves a reference to the active sheet as ws2
ThisWorkbook.Activate 'Makes this workbook the one that is displayed

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    startCol = "A"
    startRow = 13
    lastRow = .Range(startCol & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastCol = ws2.UsedRange.Columns(ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

    myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)

    Set Rng = .Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)

    ' I GET THE ERROR HERE
    .Range(.Cells(13, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Sort key1:=.Range("B13:B" & lastRow),
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Wow I think it works! :) I will get back to you tomorrow and mark it as an answer, when I have my work computer and have tested it properly. Thanks so far. Just to be sure, it sorts after the data in Column B13:B right?

Comment: It should...it's still all your code, I just made the references to `ws` point to the right place. :-)

Comment: So when I run my macros, I open the this workbook, how do I make it show instead of the other workbook? I mean, so it opens but it is still "in the background". Can you help?

Comment: Before you turn off screen updating, `wb.Activate` will display whatever workbook you set wb to. For example `ThisWorkbook.Activate` will make the workbook containing the code visible. If you want the other workbook to be visible, you'll need to Dim a Workbook variable and set it to the other workbook. IF you do that however, you should revisit any line referring to `ActiveSheet` and make sure that the active sheet is still the one you intend. Best practice would be to declare each worksheet as a separate variable and reference each one explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful explanation :) so I'm getting an error in the sorting code, probably because of the activesheet.usedrange what can I replace it with?

Comment: Edited my original answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! Can I run this sub under sheetchange so it is always sorted?

Comment: You may have an issue running it under sheetchange, again, because of the reliance on ActiveSheet. Per your code, you're relying on the `ActiveWorkbook` being different from `ThisWorkbook`. If you are running it from a worksheet event, that will no longer be true. Just like for sheets, best practice is to `Dim wb1, wb2 as Workbook` then `Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook` and `Set wb2 = workbooks("workbookname.xlsx")

Comment: Could help me with that? I get an error all the time